# Already have a python project can I set up a virtual environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I already started a python project and I found out about using virtual environments and how it is a good practice. I installed virtualenv and created a new environment. But, my existing project is still running on the default python i.e with global modules and everything. How do you get the project files to run on the virtual environment? I am using VS Code and python 3.10.1

Comment: This guide walks through setting up one. Maybe you might have missed a step: https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/

Comment: does the Activate.ps1 mean activate for the script ps1? I just did activate so if so thats why

Answer (score 0):

you will have to activate the virtual env and then reinstall all the required packages in the virtual env

Answer (score 0):

You can activate your virtual environment by saying;
`source venv/bin/activate`

then pip the required packages for your project
 `pip install package_name`

You can see all the packages you have installed with `pip freeze`

To keep the modules and versions you have installed in a file called requirements.txt;
`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

You can now install these packages to the environment and project you want with a single command.  `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I restarted VSCODE and it seemed to work in all of my files already. Is requirements.txt a quality of life thing or why is it necessary? What is the difference between that and just doing pip install [name of library] for all libraries that you require.

Comment: requirements.txt A required file for Python. Let's say I have 2 different projects that I created using Fastapi; I cannot set 2 different versions of the same module on my machine. This is where the concept of venv comes into play. So I can install the package I want and its dependencies in the virtual environment.

Comment: Let's say you took your project and shared it somewhere like github. In order not to get an error while someone else is running your project on their local machine, they set up their own virtual environment and quickly load the modules in the requirements.txt with the command I just mentioned. Thus, we avoid errors such as dependency, version etc. that modules can create. I hope this helped:)

Comment: Ok thanks. So its to make sure anyone using your code will install exactly the right versions and packages